# obtain the ssl certificate of the client in Spring Restcontroller during request

Tags: spring-security, spring-webflux, reactor-netty

We are establishing a mutual TLS connection for our application using netty and Spring RestController for server.
Post TLS handshake, when the RestController receives a https request(as part of the same TLS session), how can we obtain the ssl certificate of the client?

This is required to verify some information from the subjectAltName field of the certificate.

---

Reactor version(s) used: **1.0.23**

Other relevant libraries versions (eg. netty, ...):

- spring-boot-starter-webflux:2.7.4
- spring-boot-starter:2.7.4 ()
- spring-boot-starter-json:2.7.4
- spring-boot-starter-reactor-netty:2.7.4

---

We need channel related information in the route methods of our restcontroller

Comment: Does this answer your question? [WebClient get SSL/TLS certificates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74941489/webclient-get-ssl-tls-certificates)

Answer (score 0):

You could try to start from passing `ServerWebExchange` to your controller method.

Then get `ServerHttpRequest` and call `getSslInfo()`. From `getSslInfo()` docs:

```java
/**
 * Return the SSL session information if the request has been transmitted
 * over a secure protocol including SSL certificates, if available.
 * @return the session information, or {@code null} if none available
 * @since 5.0.2
 */
```

From `SslInfo` you can obtain `X509Certificate[]`

```java
@GetMapping
public Mono<Void> get(ServerWebExchange serverWebExchange) {
    ServerHttpRequest request = serverWebExchange.getRequest();

    Optional<X509Certificate[]> peerCertificates =
            Optional.ofNullable(request.getSslInfo())
                    .map(SslInfo::getPeerCertificates);

    if (peerCertificates.isPresent()) {
        ...
    }

    return Mono.empty();
}
```

If you want to put this logic **before** the request comes to controller, you could implement your own `WebFilter` and write the desired logic in there

the `WebFilter` method:

```java
Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, WebFilterChain chain);
```

---

Also as far as I know Spring Security has some features for validating X509 certificates. Take a look at [this article](https://www.baeldung.com/x-509-authentication-in-spring-security#2-spring-security-configuration).